# How to avoid Jmeter's error after pausing the stress test

Tags: jmeter

I am now using Jmeter to run the stress test on APIs. When I stopped the test manually by pressing the stop button, Jmeter would return "socket closed exception error".

Therefore, I would like to ask is there any way so that this error will not occur in my reports?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use GUI for running the test, it's only for tests development and debugging, you're supposed to [run your JMeter test using command-line non-GUI mode.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)
2. No matter of the way of execution forcefully stopping the test will result in non-graceful connections termination, you should rather set fixed number of iterations and/or duration in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and wait for the test completion
3. If you really need to manually stop the test you can use [`shutdown.cmd`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/bin/shutdown.cmd) script (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
4. And finally you can remove "unwanted" results i.e. in last X seconds of the test using [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/)

Comment: I will try the shutdown.cmd, thanks very much